# redirect website using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http

I have a wesite:

> http://site1.com

and a second website:

> http://89.89.89.89:8888

I want that when I acces  http://site1.com/site2/ to show the content of http://89.89.89.89:8888.
Also I want the URL to remain the same. Ex:
Instead of http://89.89.89.89:8888/Page1.htm i want the URL to be http://site1.com/site2/Page1.htm . 
Also when i navigate from Page1.htm to Page2.htm, the URL would be http://site1.com/site2/Page2.htm.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have mod_proxy loaded?

Comment: no, I do not have mod_proxy loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `proxypass` to do something like that. You need to make sure that you have `mod_proxy` loaded in apache. Then use th `P` flag in the rule. You can try it like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://89.89.89.89:8888/$1 [L,P]
```

To enable mod_proxy, you typically just need to uncomment these lines in apache config and reload/restart apache.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: I am getting: The requested URL /home/pojori/public_html89.89.89.89:8888/site2/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Comment: And also I can not verify if mod_proxy is loaded at the moment, but there are already several RewriteRule statements in the .htacces file.

Comment: Well you need to verify it then. And then get mod_proxy enabled. It does not matter about the other statements it's not a mod_rewrite problem.

Comment: Igonore my previous 2 coments. It worked. Thank you. But there is one small inconvenience. It shows the contets of http://89.89.89.89:8888/site2 not http://89.89.89.89:8888. I can work whit this, but is there a way to show the root(http://89.89.89.89:8888)?

Comment: Oh ok then just remove `$1` from the rewriterule.